# Wrong group query when trying to build dynamically

Tags: dynamic, group-by, elixir, ecto

I am trying to working on a query builder and the example/content is just imaginary.

```
query = from en in Data.InfectionRevision
query = from q in query, select: map(q, [:is_complete, :is_active])

query = from(q in query,select_merge: %{"$aggregate": %{"$max": %{^"revision_id" => max(q.revision_id)}}})
query = from(q in query,group_by: q.encounter_id,
 select_merge: %{"$group" => %{^"encounter_id" => q.encounter_id}})
```

But the query I get is having incorrect key for group, although I have passed correct key while building query. this is what I got

```
#Ecto.Query<from i0 in Data.InfectionRevision, group_by: [i0.encounter_id],
 select: merge(merge(
   map(i0, [:is_complete, :is_active]), 
   %{"$aggregate": %{"$max": %{^"revision_id" => max(i0.revision_id)}}}), 
   %{"$group" => %{^"revision_id" => i0.encounter_id}})>
```

`%{"$group" => %{^"revision_id" => i0.encounter_id}}` should be actually `%{"$group" => %{^"encounter_id" => i0.encounter_id}}`
What Step or part of the query I am building wrong? How to fix it?

Note:

- [sample project](https://github.com/tanweerdev/has_many_preload)  on which you can run/build above queries
- Please ignore the query content, it might not makes sense because its just an example and should work  dynamically as its part of dynamic query builder
- I need to build query step by step from passed params dynamically

Comment: If I dont apply aggregate, Query is build all just fine

Comment: Looks like a bug. You should probably post this in the Ecto repository's issues page

Comment: Thanks @S.B I have created an issue here https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/2979